# Dispatch an action in a connected component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a connected component that I am trying to dispatch the `clear` action from, that looks like this:

```
import {createElement} from 'react';
import reduce from 'lodash/fp/reduce';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {faShoppingCart} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {clear} from '../../action/cart';
import * as products from '../../data/items';
import Heading from '../Heading';
import styles from './styles.css';
import Item from '../Item';

const Cart = ({total, items}) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={clear}>Clear all items</button>
    <table className={styles.cartItems}>
      <tbody>
        {items.map(({...item}, id) =>
          (<Item {...item} key={id} />))}
        <tr>
          <td colSpan={4}>
            {items.length > 0 ?
              <div className={styles.total}>${total}</div> :
              <div>Your cart is empty</div>
            }
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);

export default connect((state) => {
  return {
    items: state.cart.items,
    total: reduce(
      (sum, {id, quantity}) => sum + products[id].price * quantity,
      0,
      state.cart.items
    ).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'),
  };
})(Cart);
```

For some reason, the action of `clear` is not being called at all yet other actions are. In the reducer it looks like this:

```
[CLEAR_ITEMS]: () => ({
  items: [],
}),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a mapping from the redux `dispatcher` to `props` of your `<Cart />` component by adding this to your call to `connect()`:

```
export default connect((state) => {
  return {
    items: state.cart.items,
    total: reduce(
      (sum, {id, quantity}) => sum + products[id].price * quantity,
      0,
      state.cart.items
    ).toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,'),
  };
}, 
/* Add this */ 
(dispatch) => {
   return {
       dispatchClear : () => dispatch(clear())
   }
})(Cart);
```

Now you can dispatch the `clear()` action to your reducer by adjusting your `<Cart/>` component like so:

```
/* Add dispatchClear now that it's mapped to props of your Cart component */
const Cart = ({total, items, dispatchClear}) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={dispatchClear}>Clear all items</button>
    <table className={styles.cartItems}>
      <tbody>
        {items.map(({...item}, id) =>
          (<Item {...item} key={id} />))}
        <tr>
          <td colSpan={4}>
            {items.length > 0 ?
              <div className={styles.total}>${total}</div> :
              <div>Your cart is empty</div>
            }
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Something I am still unclear on is how dispatchClear is passed into the cart component. When using your example I get this error in Chrome: `warning.js:14 mapDispatchToProps() in Connect(Cart) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.`

And when looking at it in my editor I get an error saying dispatchClear is defined but never used.

Comment: Sorry minor typo - does the update work for you? The second function passed to `connect()` created functions that invoke the dispatcher. Those functions are mapped to `props` in your component, so that your dispatcher can be invoked from the context of your component

Comment: That worked, that makes sense - thanks for the explanation and your help!

Comment: You're welcome - please consider accepting this answer if it helped you :-)

Comment: Just for noticing, if there is no mapstatetoprops, then there would not need a mapping prop dispatch, dispatch is added by default to props when bound as: connect()(componentnsme) then you may directly call this.props.dispatch(..) in your methods